# How to get the desired format for a Windows phone 8 push notification sent from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, notifications, toast

I followed this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202967(v=vs.105).aspx

It works, but the toast that appears on the phone screen contains all of this:

```
Received Toast 4:05 PM:

wp:Text1: Please

wp:Text2: Help!

wp.Param: /Page2.xaml?

NavigatedFrom=Toast Notification
```

I would like for the toast to only contain text1 and text2. In this instance I only want "Please Help!" to appear. I've looked at everything on MSDN and everywhere else on google and there is nothing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see what you want if the demo app isn't running when the toast arrives: an alert with "Please Help!" will show at the top of the screen.

If the app is running then the app's [ShellToastNotificationReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.shelltoastnotificationreceived(v=vs.105).aspx) event fires instead of the toast appearing on the phone. This lets the app decide what to show. The demo code parses the received data and explicitly adds each key and value to a string and shows it in a MessageBox. This is purely for demonstration. A real app would never do that.

Typically a real app would find the interesting information and display it in-line rather than in a MessageBox, but the details will depend on the app.

If you want to display the contents of wp:Text1 and wp:Text2 in a TextBlock you can create the string something like:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
message.AppendFormat("{0} {1}",e.Collection["wp:Text1"],e.Collection["wp:Text2"]);
MyTextBlock.Text = message;
```

In production you'd probably want to verify that wp:Text1 and wp:Text2 existed, etc.

Comment: I was unable to put it in a textblock for some reason. It seems like I don't have access to it or something. Despite that though, I used what you said about changing the message format:

message.AppendFormat("{0} {1}",e.Collection["wp:Text1"],e.Collection["wp:Text2"]);

It finally worked! Well at least it does when I'm at the windows home screen. The only problem now is that the toast I receive while in the app looks like this:

Please Help!Please Help!Please Help!

It repeats the text1/text2 combination three times every time. Any idea what might be causing this format problem?

Comment: You'd need to add a TextBlock to your Xaml. The exact way you display this will depend on what you want your app to do.

The text probably repeats because you add it to the string three times. If all you changed from the sample is the format then it's still called in a loop to add for each key (wp:Text1, wp:Text2, wp.Param).

Comment: I took it out of the loop and it works now! Even though I got it to work this way, out of curiosity I tried also using a textblock. I added a textblock to the xaml, but couldn't access it from my xaml.cs . Is there a certain way of doing this correctly?